# Setting up high availability LDAP authentication using FreeIPA

Tags: authentication, ldap, pfsense, freeipa

I am trying to setup pfSense LDAP authentication using FreeIPA master/replica nodes.

I was able to directly connect to the master LDAP server using the hostname/ip-address but when it goes down how can I make the pfSense automatically failover to the replica for authentication. It would be of immense help if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have freeipa replicas installed.

I personally used haproxy and keepalived to accomplish this. Specifics of this configuration of course depend on your networking setup. Virtual IP is 10.1.1.1 and ipa servers are 10.1.0.1 and 10.1.0.2. This is a snippet from haproxy config I use.

```
frontend ldap-proxy
  bind 10.1.1.1:636
  mode tcp
  default_backend ldap-proxy
  option tcplog

backend ldap-proxy
  option tcplog
  option tcp-check
  mode tcp
  balance roundrobin
  server ipa-server-1 10.1.0.1:636 check
  server ipa-server-2 10.1.0.2:636 check
```

Works fine with jenkins, confluence, jira, whatever.